# python Joining list elements into list of list

Tags: python

I am attempting to join certain list elements in a specific manner:
assuming i have following lists:

```
simpleline= [ 4 ]
otherline= [ 5, 7 ]
nextline=[ 1, 2 ]
```

i want to generate following lists:

```
 middlelist=[ [ 4, 5 ] , [ 4, 7 ] ]
```

then finally:

```
finallist=[ [ 4, 5, 1] , [4, 7, 1] , [ 4, 5, 2 ] , [ 4, 7, 2 ] ]
```

i have attempted the first process in a cycle:

```
simpleline= [ 4 ]
otherline= [ 5, 7 ]
nextline=[ 1, 2 ]

middlelist=[]
for element in range(len(otherline)):
           snap=simpleline[0].append(otherline[element])
           middlelist.append(snap)

print middlelist
```

however this results in error:

```
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

i appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```
finallist = list(map(list, itertools.product(*[simpleline,otherline,nextline])))

>>> finallist
[[4, 5, 1], [4, 5, 2], [4, 7, 1], [4, 7, 2]]
```

If you need the `middlelist` too:

```
middlelist = list(map(list, itertools.product(*[simpleline,otherline])))

>>> middlelist
[[4, 5], [4, 7]]
```

Comment: How can I use the midllelist in the itertools function without brackets interfering

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "interfering"? What's wrong with the brackets?

Comment: One liners are extremely catchy but without explanation are equally worthless

Comment: @Bazingaa, that's what the link is for in the post

Comment: I need to repeat the process over and don't have all lists available at the same time, the innermost nested brackets are interfering

Answer (score 0):

Can use list comprehension here, just need to concatenate for the final list

```
middle = [[i, j] for i in simpleline for j in otherline]
# [[4, 5], [4, 7]]

final = [j + [i] for i in nextline for j in middle]
# [[4, 5, 1], [4, 7, 1], [4, 5, 2], [4, 7, 2]]
```